# How to efficiently retrieve all workspaces and their users/groups

Tags: api, permissions, libraries

I have this use case where, for each workspace, I want to retrieve the users and groups that have access to it.
Right now, the only path that I see is querying the `UserRecordAccess` object for each user. In other terms...

```
SELECT RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = 'X' AND RecordId IN ('Y', 'Z', ...) AND HasReadAccess = true
```

... where

- `X` is a user
- `Y`, `Z`, ... are workspaces

This is costly if I have a lot of users and workspaces.

Is there a better path to accomplish this?